# Editing data on a file and saving it as a new file instead of overwriting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, replace, overwrite

I have a file that is an email template written so i can specifically change things based on input the user has given. (Example: a .msg file that reads "Hello! mangName - there seems to be a problem in deptName")

using .replace I am able to replace these placeholders in the email with variables in my code to generate a message displaying the user input variables.

```
with open('escalation_email.emltpl', 'r+') as f:
  content = f.read()
  f.seek(0)
  f.truncate()
  f.write(content.replace('@@@,,', lineManagerFirstName))
  f.write(content.replace('xxxxx', 'violator'))
```

However, when I do this, my template is overwritten and changed, so i can't use the .replace again because what's written in the 'placeholder' spots has been changed and overwritten.

Is there a way where I could simply use my orginal .msg file with the 'placeholder text' as a template and save a new file using that template as a base, using its formatting but not overwriting it?
So basically - using 'escalation_email.emltpl' as the template - but generating 'new-email.emltpl' as a file with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a template on a new file, read that one, and write your `UserInput.msg` separately.

If you don't want to override `content` make a copy of ir where you do replace the placeholders.

```
original_content = ''
with open('escalation_email.emltpl', 'r') as f:
  original_content = f.read()
  f.seek(0)
  f.truncate()

content = original_content

with open('userInputFile.msg', 'w') as f:
  f.write(content.replace('@@@,,', lineManagerFirstName))
  f.write(content.replace('xxxxx', 'violator'))
```

Comment: You can also open both the files(template and new file) like `with open(template_file) as template, open(new_file,’w’) as new_file:`

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the changes to the file every time you replace the contents. Remove the `f.write`. Just replace the contents and use that contents variable to write to a new file